# Change the title of a page while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

As an exercise for myself I'm trying to make a blog posting application using JavasScript, JQuery and PHP. What I want to happen is that, when you're typing, the title of the page changes. With this, I mean the title declared within the `<title></title>` tags. A good example of this is StackOverflow: when you're asking a new question, you type in the title of that post, and the page title (the one declared inside the `<head>`) changes to the title you are typing.

How is this effect done? Is it possible using only JavaScript/JQuery or do you need AJAX for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just change the title with JS:

```
document.title = 'New title';
```

About the effect you are looking for you can probably do something in the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("input").keyup(function() {
          var text = $(this).val();
          document.title = text;
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think you want to change the page `title` to whatever is typed in a `input` tag, For example

something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myInput').keyup(function () {
        $(document).attr('title', $('#myInput').val());
    });
});
```

the above will track the changes of key up (on keyboard) and get the value of the text input and set it as page title :

here a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLPfM/show

Answer (score 0):

To change the page title, you can do one of two things:

```
//plain javascript
document.title = 'My JavaScript title!';

//jQuery
$(document).attr('title', 'My jQuery Title');
```

In order to change it while typing, hook up an `keyup` event:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) 
{ 
    //Check the keycode using e.keyCode
});
```

This will bind it to the `document`, which means anytime a key is pressed, within an input or otherwise, your event will fire. You could also bind it to a textbox so that it will only fire when you type within the input (which is probably what you want to do).

If you bind to the `document`, like shown above, you'll have to check the `keyCode` and append the value onto your title. If you bind to an input, you can grab the input value and set the title to the new value:

```
$('#myinput').keyup(function(e)
{
    var text = $(this).val();
    document.title = text;
});
```